# TCP Error: ODBC connection with Azure SQL Database

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database

Using an Azure SQL Database for my application with a php exchange. I had a MSSQL express server running locally but when I moved to Azure I am receiving a connection error:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No such host is known. , SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\UnitySQL\connect.php on line 13
```

My code is as follows (changed login details but format is the same):

```
<?php 
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $user = 'Login@Azure';
    $pass = 'azure';
    $server = 'azure.database.secure.windows.net,port';
    $database = 'db';


// No changes needed from now on
    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};;SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database";
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
    $q = "select top 1 u.First, u.UserEmail, u.UserTelephone, u.UserId, MAX
(us.session) as sessionid, us.LastQuestion as LastQuestion from [user] as u LEFT OUTER join usersession as us
On u.UserId = us.userid

where UserEmail='$username' AND UserTelephone='$password'
group by u.[First], u.UserEmail, u.UserTelephone, u.UserId, LastQuestion
Order by sessionid DESC";
    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$q);
    $num_rows = odbc_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($result);
        echo "First=". $row['First'] . "/" . "UserId=" . $row['UserId'] . "/" . "SessionId=" . $row['sessionid'] . "/" . "LastQuestion=" . $row['LastQuestion'] . "/" . "UserEmail=" . $row['UserEmail']. "/" . "UserTelephone=" . $row['UserTelephone'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $server setting is incorrect.  Instead of

```
$server = 'azure.database.secure.windows.net,port';
```

try

```
$server = 'tcp:<YOUR_SRV_NAME>.database.windows.net,1433';
```

Replace  with the name of your SQL Database *server*.
For more information take a look at [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-php-how-to-use/).